# Permission of file keeps changing back

Tags: fedora, keyboard, brightness

I have an Asus G75VX laptop running Fedora 20.

The laptop has a keyboard backlight that is turned on by default every time I log in, which is undesirable behavior.

I tried to solve the problem by doing the following:

- Become root and use the `chmod` command to change the permissions on the `/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness` file, which contains the keyboard backlight brightness value, from 644 to 666.
- Add the following commands to my `~/.bash_profile`:

  `kbd_brightness_file="/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness"
   if [[ -e $kbd_brightness_file ]]; then
       echo 0 > "$kbd_brightness_file"
   fi`

I expect that when I log in, the `.bash_profile` will be run, and will write the appropriate value to the brightness file, thereby turning the keyboard backlight off.

However, this does not work. Every time I restart my computer, the brightness file's permissions change back to 644!

I wonder if the file is being re-created every time the computer restarts...

Comment: "sysfs is an in-memory filesystem" [mochel.pdf - The sysfs filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/mochel/doc/papers/ols-2005/mochel.pdf)

Comment: I see...so it actually IS being recreated every time I restart the computer? Haven't had a chance to fully read the paper.

Comment: Yes. Consider using an init script. http://askubuntu.com/questions/234551/permanent-permission-change-to-sys-file

Comment: Ha! What are the chances that the question you pointed to would also be about the backlight of an Asus computer!